# Retrying a RestRequest

Tags: c#, generics, async-await

I wrote a method that lets me retry RestSharp requests when a specific exception is thrown.
Here's the code for that method:

```
private async Task<T_Out> RunRequestWithRetry<T_In, T_Out>(Func<SignatureAccount, T_In, T_Out> request, SignatureAccount signatureAccount, T_In requestBody) where T_Out : Task
{
    try
    {
        var result = request.Invoke(signatureAccount, requestBody) as Task;
        await result;
        return result as T_Out;
    }
    catch (AMAApiException<ErrorResult> apiEx)
    {
        if (apiEx.ErrorType != AMAErrorType.TokenNeedsRefresh)
            throw apiEx;

        // Refresh Tokens
        var signatureAccountService = new SignatureAccountService(MvcApplication.Config);
        var newSignatureAccount = await signatureAccountService.UpdateTokens(signatureAccount);
        if (newSignatureAccount == null)
            throw apiEx;

        UpdateSignatureAccount = true;
        StorageService.SignatureAccount.SaveState(newSignatureAccount);
        return request.Invoke(newSignatureAccount, requestBody); 
    }
}
```

This works well enough since all the requests that'll be passing through this method have the same signature and all of them will return a `Task`.

My only issue with this code is that I need to call `await` 2 when I call it, for example:

```
var credentialsListResponse =  await await RunRequestWithRetry(GetCredentialsList, process.SignatureAccount, credentialsListBody);
```

I tried to return only the `T_Out` since I specified it to be of type `Task` but visual studio does not like that... So I had to wrap the return with a Task, but this makes my method return `Task<Task<Type>>`.

Is there a way to make this more elegant, maybe remove one of the await calls.

Comment: BTW You can call the [`Unwrap`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-unwrap-a-nested-task), ([1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap)) to flatten `Task<Task<T>>` to `Task<T>`

Comment: A cool method to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong with my logic, it was quite a simple fix that solves the double await problem, I just needed to make the signature of the method Func<SignatureAccount, T_In, Task<T_Out>> this way the T_Out will be the correct type and I can return Task<T_Out>.

I also took the advise by @Perfect28 and extracted the refreshToken logic to a new method called UpdateTokensAndRetry, this works for me since I only need to retry once after refreshing the tokens, since I only want to refresh when the tokens exipe.

Here's the code sample with the solution:

```
private async Task<T_Out> RunRequestWithRetry<T_In, T_Out>(Func<SignatureAccount, T_In, Task<T_Out>> request, SignatureAccount signatureAccount, T_In requestBody)
{
    try
    {
        return await request.Invoke(signatureAccount, requestBody);
    }
    catch (AMAApiException<ErrorResult> apiEx)
    {
        if (apiEx.ErrorType != AMAErrorType.TokenNeedsRefresh)
            throw apiEx;

        return await UpdateTokensAndRetry(request, signatureAccount, requestBody, apiEx);
    }
}

private async Task<T_Out> UpdateTokensAndRetry<T_In, T_Out, T_Ex>(Func<SignatureAccount, T_In, Task<T_Out>> request, SignatureAccount signatureAccount, T_In requestBody, T_Ex apiEx) where T_Ex : Exception
{
    // Refresh Tokens
    var signatureAccountService = new SignatureAccountService(MvcApplication.Config);
    var newSignatureAccount = await signatureAccountService.UpdateTokens(signatureAccount);
    if (newSignatureAccount == null)
        throw apiEx;

    UpdateSignatureAccount = true;
    StorageService.SignatureAccount.SaveState(newSignatureAccount);
    return await request.Invoke(newSignatureAccount, requestBody);
}
```

And now I can call the method like this:

```
var signHashesResponse = await RunRequestWithRetry(GetSignedHashes, process.SignatureAccount, signHashesRequest);
```

Comment: This answer is okay, but it might be better to delete it and ask a follow up question with a link pointing back to this question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont quite understand what you are trying to tell me, what follow up question should I make? I don't get why I should delete it?

Answer (score 3):

Here are few suggestions :

First, make a loop

- the readability is improved as you will see only `request.Invoke(signatureAccount, requestBody)` call in one place.
- you will get rid of the nested Task
- it will be more simple if your customer decide to ask 3 retries or more.

Second, `RunRequestWithRetry` is fullfilling too much roles. It should focus only on retrying a request as its name suggest. Refreshing tokens have no place here. A trick could be passing a "CleanupOnException" task as argument that the caller should provide.

Finally, if you can use some nuget packages, there is a very serious and popular one (top 7 non-microsoft nuget packages) which do exactly what you want in an elegant manner: **[Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly)**.

Comment: Thank you for your sugestion, I dont really require do define a number of retries, I only need to retry once in case the token has expired, thats why the code to refresh the token is there, but I could it refresh the tokens in a separate method, anyways I managed to find a solution for the problem I was having.